# Google App Engine ndb performance on repeated property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Do I pay a penalty on query performance if I choose to query `repeated` property?  For example:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    login_providers = ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=true)

fbkey = ndb.Key("ProviderId", 1, "ProviderName", "FB")
for entry in User.query(User.login_providers == fbkey):
    # Do something with entry.key
```

vs

```
class User(ndb.Model)
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty()

class UserProvider(ndb.Model):
    user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    login_provider = ndb.KeyProperty()

for entry in UserProvider.query(
    UserProvider.user_key == auserkey,
    UserProvider.login_provider == fbkey
):
    # Do something with entry.user_key
```

Based on the documentation from GAE, it seems that Datastore take care of indexing and the first less verbose option would be using the index.  However, I failed to find any documentation to confirm this.

**Edit**

The sole purpose of `UserProvider` in the second example is to create a one-to-many relationship between a user and it's login_provider.  I wanted to understand if it worth the trouble of creating a second entity instead of querying on `repeated` property.  Also, assume that all I need is the key from the `User`.

Comment: It's unclear whether you also have a UserProvider class in the first version, or whether you just create Keys pointing nowhere (which is permissible, BTW :-).  The two queries are not equivalent since one returns User entities and the other UserProvider entities.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum I updated the question and hopefully is clearer now.  It did take me a while to understand what is a ndb.Key, given that you can create a Key that points to nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  But you'll raise your write costs because each entry needs to be indexed, and write costs are based on the number of indexes updated.

Comment: OTOH the query in the first case should be cheaper. So it comes down to how often you add/remove a provider.

Comment: OK, sounds like you needn't bother with the UserProvider. And maybe you should just use a StringProperty (set to e.g. "FB") instead of a KeyProperty pointing nowhere. It's fewer bytes to store.